Overflow hidden on a sticky div breaks ability to scroll to the bottom on mobile browsers
I wanted to use a scroll effect (parallax + filters) in a very simple page. It's just a sticky 120vh div with a background image and some text.
Everything works fine in the desktop browser and with the mobile view of desktop browsers, however on my real device I experience a weird glitch.
If you scroll up and back down the panel gets stuck because the container shrinks and doesn't scroll to the end anymore. This only happens when you scroll down and then back up.
I presume it's due to the window changing size because of the scrollbar appearing.
When I don't scroll manually, but instead click on the panel which does a scrollToTop / scrollToBottom everything works fine. But as soon as I manually scroll from the bottom back to the top the site breaks.
Here are three screenshots. I'm using a Pixel 5 and Chrome (on Android).
You can experience this live by visiting https://javascript-moe-git-preview-scroll-issue-c5h8nnao4s-projects.vercel.app/about on a similar device (I guess).
I deployed a "dirty workaround" on production which you can see at https://javascript.moe/about which simply finishes the animation earlier, but you can still experience the issue when scrolling down, back up and back down again. When you reload the page after it's stuck, you can see it revert back to normal on page unload.
Here is the code that causes the problem. I tried to isolate it, but I no matter what I try removing, the bug keeps persisting until I remove the content entirely.
Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem and the code:





import { getVH, scrollToTop } from "../lib/util"
import { StickySection, sectionCtx } from "../components/AnimatedSection"
import { BackgroundImage } from "../components/BackgroundImage"
import { Parallax } from "../components/anim/Parallax"
import {
    motion,
    useScroll, useTransform
} from 'framer-motion';
import ArrowBack from '../assets/arrowback.svg?react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AboutSectionProps } from "@/lib/types";
import { ABOUT_TEXT } from "@/lib/const";

export const AboutPage = () => {
    return <>
        <StickySection height='120lvh' >
            <AboutSection text={ABOUT_TEXT} />
        </StickySection >
    </>
}

export const AboutSection = ({ text }: AboutSectionProps) => {
    const { ref: scrollRef } = useContext(sectionCtx);
    const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
        layoutEffect: true,
        target: scrollRef || undefined,
        offset: ["start start", "end end"]
    });

    const dist = getVH(50)
    const offset = -dist;
    const blur = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ['blur(4px)', 'blur(0px)'])
    const rblur = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ['brightness(100%) blur(0px) saturate(100%)', 'brightness(80%) blur(4px) saturate(140%)'])
    const background = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ['#FFFFFF11', '#00000033'])
    const overflowY = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ['hidden', 'auto']);

    return <>
        <BackgroundImage src="/images/wallpaper/5.webp" alt="Seepark in Freiburg" />
        <div className='w-[80ch] max-w-[calc(100vw-32px)] absolute top-0'>
            <Parallax distance={32 * 2} offset={32 * 1} className="flex"  >
                <Link to="/" className="flex">
                    <ArrowBack style={{ fill: 'white' }} />
                    <h2>Back</h2>
                </Link>
            </Parallax>
            <Parallax distance={dist - 32 * 4} offset={offset + 32 * 2}>
                <button
                    onClick={scrollToTop}
                >
                    <motion.div
                        style={{
                            background,
                            backdropFilter: rblur,
                            overflowY
                        }}
                        className="p-4 rounded-md shadow-lg shadow-black max-h-[calc(100svh-120px)]" >
                        <motion.p style={{ filter: blur, textShadow: '0px 0px 1px black' }}>{text}</motion.p>
                    </motion.div>
                </button>
            </Parallax>
            <Parallax
                distance={dist - 32 * 2} offset={offset + 32} className="w-full absolute top-0 ml-4"
            >
                <button
                    className="w-fit"
                    onClick={scrollToTop}
                >
                    <h1 style={{ textShadow: '0px 0px 3px black' }}>About Me</h1>
                </button>
            </Parallax>
        </div>
    </>
}

Once you scroll down and back up you can not scroll down again.
What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?
Edit: The issue seems to be caused by a combination of sticky, overflow: hidden, height: 100vh and a child elements overflowing the container.
A dirty workaround is to decrease the range of framers animation from [0, 1] to [0, 0.75] in order to let the animation unfold before the body reaches the bottom of the page.
Still no clue how to resolve this.
- C5H8NNaO4/javascript.moe/blob/master/src/pages/AboutPage.tsx

I tried your website on my Galaxy S24 phone. The issue is you have 2 scrollers one on your page and another one for the About Me Card (or anything you call it!). I would remove the card's scrollers for <480 width screens by customizing the the styling for mobile screens, a simple @media screen and (max-width: 480px){...} in your css where you disable scrolling on the card, and make the font smaller and set the height of the card tall enough to show the text.

the vercel link you provided is not working, it shows 404

Thank you very much for the suggestion, unfortunately this issue also happens without the second scroller. The main page has a workaround which hides the issue, please visit this commit to see the issue without workaround. The only way I found was to disable overflow, but that's not an option as I need it.

I've tested on android Chrome 127.0.6.533.84, and it works fine, what's your chrome version?

it also works fine with MacOS Chrome  ( 126.0.6478.185 ) on DevTools mobile preview

Safari on Mac, it shows completely white screen.

@CyrusRaoufi I deployed the wrong commit. Can you please re-check Android Chrome? It also shows on a real iOS device, but slightly different. It snaps the scroll instead of breaking it completely. The Devtools preview works on all browsers I tested.

OK, now I can see the problem on Android, works fine on MacOS Chrome, but still white screen on Safari Version 14.1.3 (16611.3.10.1.19)

That's because some new things like 100lvh aren't yet supported by Safari <15, but I don't care for older browsers for now. I'm mostly looking for a fix for latest android chrome versions.

it seems that framer-motion has some issue related to scrolling, I am working on it.  https://github.com/framer/motion/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+scroll

You can also try another library like
https://www.react-spring.dev/docs/components/parallax

@CyrusRaoufi I don't think it's framer-motion, if you use safari mobile on iOS you'll notice weird snapping behaviour which only the browser can cause. It's similar to chrome, but it doesn't get stuck completely.

Well I am really not sure about it  because framer-motion now has a lot of open bug related to scroll behavior. I'm going to make a isolated version of the source to submit on framer-motion github. Do you have any single page isolated version ?

The problem was fixed after I changed the position and display of the <h1> tag.
<h1 style={{ textShadow: '0px 0px 3px black', display:'inline',position:'relative' }}>About Me</h1>

It seems this issue occurred because the <h1> tag was behaving like it was sticky, sticking to the top of its parent tag and preventing it from moving.


Preview
Source

However, this isn't normal behavior. When the text gets stuck, switching to another browser tab and then back fixes the issue.
This means it may be a Chrome bug.

Unfortunately, the master branch contains the workaround using the range from [0, 0.75] to end the animation earlier.  The issue still persists with your changes.
Kindly see this branch where the issue is present despite having it relative and inline: https://github.com/C5H8NNaO4/javascript.moe/blob/preview/scroll-issue/src/pages/AboutPage.tsx

The vercel link in my question now has the changes you suggested deployed, but it still happens on chrome for android

are you sure? because when I frok the repo, I clearly saw the issue.

Yes, you right.

I'll award you the bounty tomorrow even if the bug is not solved. Maybe I'll add another one to draw more attention. Thanks for taking the time to look into it. No idea why this is so hard to pinpoint.

Thank you for your kindness, I will continue on this issue and if find the answer I will update this question. Good luck

@media (max-width: 768px) { .sticky-section { height: calc(100vh - 50px); } }

a code only answer is never as useful as code with an explanation. Moreover, when posting code, please format it properly.
